# How to get changing content from PHP in web and console?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When i creating a quiz, i found something interesting. When trying to change content with PHP using jQuery everything changing in web. row1 as row 1, row2 as row2; question display correctly, but when i would like to get value from question 2 i gat value from question 1. So question only load value, doesn't mean if i'm on question 1,2,3,4,5,6 or 10. I get value from 1st displayed question.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var quizCount = 1;
    $("#next").click(function(){
        quizCount = quizCount+1;

        $("#quiz").load("load-quiz.php",{
            quizNewCount : quizCount
        });
    });

    $('.service-container').each(function(){
        $("input[name=quizid"+quizCount+"]:radio").change(function () {
            return ans = $("input[name=quizid"+quizCount+"]:checked").val();
        }); 

    }); 
});
```

That is a part of my code, but most interesting, as you see i using increasing value for "quizId". Is same file have div with id  quiz.

PHP inside quiz:

```
<h3><?=$row['topic'];?></h3>
<h4><?=$row['question'];?></h4>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="<?= $choice ?>" value="<?= $ans_array[0]?>">
    <label id="<?= $ans_array[0];?>">A) <?= $ans_array[0];?>
    </label></br>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="radio" name="<?= $choice ?>" value="<?=$ans_array[1]?>">
    <label id="<?= $ans_array[1];?>">B) <?= $ans_array[1];?>
    </label></br>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="radio" name="<?= $choice ?>" value="<?=$ans_array[2]?>">
    <label id="<?= $ans_array[2];?>">C) <?= $ans_array[2];?>
    </label></br>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="radio" name="<?= $choice ?>" value="<?=$ans_array[3]?>">
    <label id="<?= $ans_array[3];?>">D) <?= $ans_array[3];?>
    </label></br>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="radio" name="<?= $choice ?>" value="<?=$ans_array[4]?>">
    <label id="<?= $ans_array[4];?>">E) <?= $ans_array[4];?>
    </label></br>
</div>
```

same code is a part of my grade.php file.
Resuming:
server side $choice = client side ans;

every time value is equal. but i get result only for 1st displayed question , when i load my grade.php i don't have a output because, i getting value only from 1st question.
Can somebody give me some clue?!

Update:
That php display title from database

```
<h3><?=$row['topic'];?></h3>
```

and i get like:

"Javascript "

when i use ajax call to load next title from database:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var quizCount = 1;
        $("#next").click(function(){
            quizCount = quizCount+1;

            $("#quiz").load("load-quiz.php",{
                quizNewCount : quizCount
            });
        });
```

I get "CSS", when click again i get "HTML", click again "jQuery" etc... everything display correct, but not for value, every time i see "Javascript" value.

Question updated

Comment: What console output are you talking about?

Comment: F12 source. And there you have output

Comment: That doesn't exlplain anything about what you expect to see and what is different about what you do see

Comment: question updated

Comment: Nothing should change in `source`. If you want to see updates look in element inspector. If you want to inspect the request look in network

Comment: i need to get value from each input name, but i get always value from 1st one. how i should do that?

Comment: updated question... please up vote...

Comment: Seems like an ID issue, like you're trying to fetch $("#id").val(); and they all have the same ID, making it return the first value only. Do you have an example of your AJAX request? I don't see any AJAX function at all in the examples you provided.